# In MVC how to manage separate log in and log out for different areas and front end

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, form-authentication

In MVC I am having four different areas in one application. so when I open two areas in one browser and logged out from one, it'll also logged me out from another area.

I am using form authentication in my MVC application that contains one area-Admin and fron-end. When i logged in admin and if i open front end in same browser or when i logged out from front end then it will also logged me out from admin.

Is it possible to manage area wise authentication  using form authentication.

I can manage different web.config for all areas using below code:

```
<location path="Admin" >    
<system.web>
        <authentication mode="Forms">
            <forms 
                name="MyAreaCookie"
                loginUrl="~/MyArea/Account/LogOn" 
                timeout="2880" 
            />
        </authentication>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

But above code will only applicable on views under "Area".
Now the situation is when i log out from any "Area" section, it'll automatically log out me from front-end.
Does anyone have solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

No.

You can however use different sessions in different tabs in the way that I describe here: http://blog.gauffin.org/2012/02/get-a-unique-session-in-each-browser-tab/

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. But here is it possible to have different authentication tickets for different log in or for different area?